# Google Maps API V3 Street View Not Showing Compass for Handsfree Orientation

Tags: google-maps-api-3

If you go to my site www.buildinglit.com and do a search and then move the pegman onto the map for street view viewing you cannot enter the compass mode for hands free orientation for the view mode. You have to use your finger to or thumb to "turn your head" around... I want the user to be able to just face a direction and the camera turns just like in regular google maps. Is this possible in the API? It looks like it is to me from the documentation but for some reason I cannot get this to work Correctly. Tried on Android and IPhone same result.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/) lets you embed a static (non-interactive) Street View panorama or thumbnail into your web page, without the use of JavaScript. The viewport is defined with URL parameters sent through a standard HTTP request, and is returned as a static image.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988354 &fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10 &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

A Street View Image request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?parameters
```

The image is specified using request parameters. As is standard in URLs, all parameters are separated using the ampersand (&) character. Allowed parameters and their possible values are listed below.

- **location** can be either a text string (such as Chagrin Falls, OH) or a lat/lng value (40.457375,-80.009353). The Google Street View Image API will snap to the panorama photographed closest to this location. Because Street View imagery is periodically refreshed, and photographs may be taken from slightly different positions each time, it's possible that your location may snap to a different panorama when imagery is updated.
  Or:
- **pano** is a specific panorama ID. These are generally stable.
- **key** allows you to monitor your application's API usage in the Google Developers Console; enables per-key instead of per-IP-address quota limits; and ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary. For more information, see Get a Key and Signature.
  Note: Google Maps APIs Premium Plan customers may use either an API key and digital signature, or a valid client ID and digital signature, in your Street View requests. Get more information on authentication parameters for Premium Plan customers.

For more information on using the Google Street View Image API, or other Google Maps API products, be sure to check out the [Maps API Support](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/).